# Should I add a new answer if a previous one is partially correct?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by a question like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93919/do-challenges-provide-any-rewards).

If a different user has posted an answer that is at least half correct (or so), should I edit that answer to more thoroughly answer the question, or should I answer again with the combined knowledge to sell myself out to rep?  Or should I comment on the answer with the additional info?  Is there a protocol for this or is it entirely up to the user?

Comment: This is really case by case.  There are a lot of factors that will guide which is the best approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would never edit an answer to add new content. Editing should be reserved IMO for corrections like grammar, spelling, major character names misspelled etc. I recommend that you mention the points the other answer contains and attribute it to the user that answered.

You could consider [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64151/how-do-i-find-meridias-beacon-in-skyrim) which was answered by someone and accepted. But I felt compelled to post my own, since I felt something was missing. I acknowledged the accepted answer and the person who answered in my answer.

`Or should I comment on the answer with the additional info?`

You could add a comment if you think your comment could add to the answer, but by itself can not be a complete answer.

`or should I answer again with the combined knowledge to sell myself out to rep?`

I do believe if it is rep-whoring, we would notice something like that. And the community would react. Check out [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42214/what-is-fus-ro-dah) asked by our esteemed [agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86). I thought it got closed for rep-whoring, I did comment as well. Not for the rep but for the hat. But did get re-opened again.

On SO it is not uncommon to see someone post 
`@User was right, in addition to what he said, but here is a caveat` as part of a person's answer.

I personally do not think Arqade works quite the same way. We are different from most other SE sites in this regard.

Ultimately as @MBraedley put it, it depends on a case by case basis.